# What means Java FC

Tags: java

I have a test to do for a company, they said:

> You've been assigned to take an assessment: Java (30 min), JAVA FC (40 min).

What means JAVA FC? I never heard before that.

edit: on google I found Java Foundation Classes, but I don't know if Java FC refers at the same thing.

Comment: let us know once you get to know

Comment: @Ravi: I will do that

Comment: It is an Indonesian Football (Soccer) Club :) Maybe they meant JavaFX?

Comment: Did they tell you Java FC or was it in writing? Probably You either misheard or it's a typo. It's possible they meant JFC as answered by Florian and then it probably means they are going to ask you about Swing but it's a very weird way to say it. You should ask them what they meant.

Comment: If it matters to you, ask them.  They are the only people who know what they really meant.  Otherwise just take the assessment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming - it's about what a particular company meant in a particular message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's an abbreviation for Java Foundation Classes, a term which has been used long time ago in a galaxy far, far away.
See [Wikipedia on Java Foundation Classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Foundation_Classes).

Comment: I googled before that and I had the same result. I ask here for confirm

Answer (score 1):

I asked them and they confirm that it was: Java Foundation Classes: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faqs-140150.html